# Quad socket motherboards that support mezzanine or daughtercards with additional CPU sockets?

Tags: motherboard, server

Years ago Tyan had the Thunder line of motherboards, mostly in the EATX form factor. They were notable for being quad socket designs and also supported the addition of a mezzanine card with another 4 CPU sockets with another 16 RAM slots.

Are there any currently produced quad socket motherboards in a desktop/workstation compatible form factor like EATX that can also be expanded with a daughter or mezzanine card with additional CPUs?

Comment: It seems that those boards you're looking for are from a past era of HPC. Single systems with dozens of CPUs are no longer *necessary* for HPC as multiple independent (*and even virtualized*) systems have become a viable and cost effective solution for lots of applications. GPU Compute has also taken the multiple CPU concept further with thousands of cores per PCIe slot if your software can make use of them. Could you explain your use case for having so many CPUs in a single system? Is it a legacy application you need to support?

Comment: This isn't for any particular reason beyond the computer equivalent of hot rodding and "bench racing". Back when the Thunder line was available, I had a dream computer build with that as the foundation. The idea being building the most insane, over the top personal workstation possible.

Comment: Well these days you could go a lot further with virtualization or cloud computing technology, and probably for cheaper. You could build a a super computer from many simple servers and run a virtualized PC that can access the cores of all of them!

Comment: Is this a real project you intend to finish, or just an idea you had? How overkill exactly do you want it to be? Regular boards with 2-4 sockets allow for pretty impressive stats these days. 128 cores, 4TB of memory and more, tons of PCIe lanes... Boards with support for up to 8 CPUs (and more memory) exist, but you would have a hard time sourcing it without buying a whole server. And converting that into anything that could be called "workstation" would be challenging. Also: most of the software used for "bench racing" does not run particularly well on these types of machines...

Comment: Top of the line in terms of CPU count, core count, memory capacity: https://www.deltacomputer.com/d80x-m8-ps.html good luck!

Comment: Well, in terms of virtualization, I have considered the possibility of a Beowulf cluster, which would certainly give me plenty of cores and memory capacity. I only lean to a mobo with mezzanine for simplicity of wiring. I have no *immediate* plans to build, but have hopes of getting started in the fall.  And for what it's worth, I have seen the problem with high socket count boards only being sold as server systems, usually for crazy money by hobbyist standards.

Comment: I read recently that Marvell just announced ARM servers with 96 cores and 384 threads (SMT4). Also look into Xeon Phi - that's the modern processor add-in card, more flexible than GPU computing.